# Access a web application from windows which is running on SunOS box

Tags: web-applications

I have a web application running on Sun OS platform, and I want to access that application from windows.

What should be the requirement, do I need to open the firewall or port number on which web application is running.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is listening on an external (or NATed) IP you can open a firewall port to access it.  IF you don't know the port number, on GNU ( not sure about SunOS) `lsof | grep LISTEN` is a fairly simple way to see what's listening on a network port.

As a Systems Administrator, I don't like making holes in my firewall.  I'd suggest a user in your position use `ssh` to create a tunnel from a local port on their workstation to a port on the remote host.  Admins can even restrtict accounts to be able to only open tunnels and only to specific ports, on a per user basis.  And your traffic will be sent over an encrypted pipe, and you won't have to worry about opening your firewall at all (assuning you have SSH access to the box).

You'd likely use Putty to do that from windows land.